# Blank value when parameterizing SQL query

Tags: sql, vba

I'm having issues with apostrophes so I'm trying to parameterize to avoid them. This code runs without eror, but in the database instead of seeing "test" it's just blank. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

```vb
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
'Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = constring
conn.Open
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "declare @gmnv varchar(20), @recid varchar(15), @Value1 varchar(200) " _
               & " set nocount OFF " _
               & " EXEC Castell_Create @gmnv OUTPUT " _
               & " EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'accountno', '" & _
                        Sheets("Quote Sheet").Range("N22").Value & "' " _
               & " EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'filename', @Value1 " _ 
               & " EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'user', 'MASTER' " _
               & " EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'notes', 'Quote ZT19-01'" _
               & " EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'ref', '" & _
                         Replace(Sheets("Quote Sheet").Range("G7").Value, "'", "''") _
                         & " - "  & _
                         Sheets("Quote Sheet").Range("B11").Value & "' " _
               & " EXEC Castell_WriteLinkedDoc @gmnv" _
               & " EXEC Castell_GetValue @gmnv, 'recid', @recid OUTPUT" _
               & " EXEC dbo.Castell_Delete @gmnv"

Dim param1 As ADODB.Parameter
Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@Value1", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 8, "test")
cmd.Parameters.Append param1
cmd.Execute
```

Comment: I made substantial edits to your hard to read query for line breaks. Please fix if quotes were maladjusted.

Comment: Have you tried adVarChar as parameter input type.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, ADO Command object does not support named parameters like `@value1` but positional parameters. Therefore, simply place `?` marks at needed positions and bind them in order. Also, avoid any and all concatenation and use parameters consistently:

```vb
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

' PREPARED STATEMENT - NO DATA (THREE UNQUOTED ? MARKERS)
sql_command = "declare @gmnv varchar(20), @recid varchar(15), @Value1 varchar(200) " _
               & " set nocount OFF " _
               & " EXEC Castell_Create @gmnv OUTPUT " _
               & " EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'accountno', ? " _
               & " EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'filename', ? " _ 
               & " EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'user', 'MASTER' " _
               & " EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'notes', 'Quote ZT19-01'" _
               & " EXEC Castell_SetValue @gmnv, 'ref', ? " _
               & " EXEC Castell_WriteLinkedDoc @gmnv" _
               & " EXEC Castell_GetValue @gmnv, 'recid', @recid OUTPUT" _
               & " EXEC dbo.Castell_Delete @gmnv"

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandText = sql_command

    ' BIND PARAMS (ADJUST TYPE AND LENGTH AS NEEDED)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("prm1", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, _
         Sheets("Quote Sheet").Range("N22").Value
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("prm2", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 8, "test")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("prm3", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, _
         Sheets("Quote Sheet").Range("G7").Value & " - " & _
         Sheets("Quote Sheet").Range("B11").Value

    .Execute
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions. I reworked my project to remove apostrophes from file names to bypass the issue.

Comment: So you do not employ parameterization as shown above?